# Subtask vs sub-task vs sub task

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

We provide tests for candidates. Each test consists of several tasks. Each task may consist of several subtasks / sub-tasks / sub tasks?

So far we've used all these terms both internally and in communication with customers. At least we should be consistent and choose one over the other. But which one?

Comment: A "sub task" is a task assigned to, or concerned with, a [sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub). Write "sub-" with capitalized words (e.g. sub-Saharan, sub-Arctic), otherwise it's a plain prefix with no hyphen.

Comment: Subtask.

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Thank you guys, the answer and comments were all helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the guidelines from the above reference, [the definition of subtask](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subtask) makes it a single word: subtask.

Comment: True, but the "reference" doesn't cite any conversation with God confirming that these are definitively "the" rules that must be followed by mankind.

Comment: Thank you guys, the answer and comments were all helpful.